# Is this template syntax illegal?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting an "internal compiler error" with this using GCC 4.9.2:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename, int, template <typename U, U, U> class>
struct Sort;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T N, T... Is,
          template <typename U, U, U> class Comparator>
struct Sort<T, Z<N, Is...>, 0, Comparator> {
  template <T I>
  struct less_than : std::integral_constant<bool, Comparator<T, I, N>::value> {
  };
};

int main() {}
```

The error message states:

> c:\ADandD>g++ -std=c++14 ComparatorAndSorterTGeneralized.cpp
>   ComparatorAndSorterTGeneralized.cpp:254:80: internal compiler error: in tsubst,
>   at cp/pt.c:11738
>
> ```
> template<T I>
> struct less_than : std::integral_constant<bool, Comparator<T,I,N>::value> {};
>                                                                               ^
> ```
>
> Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.

The issue is the template `<typename U, U, U> class Comparator` being used. I've never tried this before. At first I tried the template `<typename T, T, T> class Comparator`, but that would not compile because of the template shadowing, so I knew that was illegal. And then changing it to U still did not compile, so I thought the whole idea is not allowed.

Update:  Upon instantiating, this compiles in Visual Studio 2015 Preview:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename, int, template <typename U, U, U> class>
struct Sort;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T N, T... Is,
          template <typename U, U, U> class Comparator>
struct Sort<T, Z<N, Is...>, 0, Comparator> {
  template <T I>
  struct less_than : std::integral_constant<bool, Comparator<T, I, N>::value> {
  };
};

template <int...>
struct index_sequence {};

template <typename T, T A, T B>
    struct LessThan : std::integral_constant < bool,
    A<B> {};

enum { QuickSort, MergeSort, InsertionSort };

int main() {
  Sort<int, index_sequence<4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7>, QuickSort, LessThan> quickSort;
}
```

Comment: "Internal compiler error" is a bug in the compiler, by definition. Regardless of the answer to your question, please submit a bug report.

Comment: Well . . . um . . . did you submit a bug report?

Comment: compiles in clang++, internal compiler error in both gcc4.9 and gcc5

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 also compiles it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Did you actually instantiate the templates involved? Because VC++ is different from GCC/Clang and doesn't do much beyond a simple syntax check if you don't actually use the templates.

Comment: To the people downvoting: Regardless of him submitting a bug report, the question is still valid: If it compiles on clang or VS it doesn't necessarily mean the syntax is legal as per the standard.

Comment: I've gotten compiler errors in GCC when using nasty template expansions by running out of memory in the substitutions. Any chance that's what's going on?

Comment: @yzt I did not change the sample code.  Since it didn't instantiate anything, neither did I.

Comment: Above is a sample code with instantiation.  It compiles on VS2015 Preview.  Might that be indication that the syntax is legal?

Comment: For reference, you can run the code here and get the same error: http://cpp.sh/9maf

Comment: @CássioRenan Correct, but it's bits of code with a "is this valid?" question added to it, without any reasoning why it might be or not be valid, or why it's difficult to determine, or what a non-buggy compiler says about it (initial version of the question). That would normally count as sufficient lack of research effort for me to downvote. Because of the update that covers VS2015 preview behaviour, I'll refrain from voting, but I actually still don't think it's a very good question.

Comment: I understand this code about as much as g++ does

Comment: Why do you think this code is illegal?

Comment: Because of the `template <typename U, U, U> class Comparator` being used.  I've never tried this before.  At first I tried `template <typename T, T, T> class Comparator`, but that would not compile because of the template shadowing, so I knew that was illegal.  And then changing it to U still did not compile, so I thought the whole idea is not allowed.

Comment: @hvd yes, of course. You make a good point. Still, maybe the OP simply didn't have the means or basic knowledge to know where to start looking(I wouldn't. What to look for? template with type and value of that type as parameters? not a friendly question for a search engine). IMHO, giving more information doesn't always depend solely on effort.

Comment: I suggest a minimal example that exhibits the incorrect behavior.

Comment: @WillBriggs if this is non standard code, providing such an example may be impossible (as there is no correct behaviour to be incorrect). I do agree that a simplified example would help convey the question though.

Comment: The Intel compiler (15.0.2) also fails with with a very strange `internal error: bad pointer` on the instantiation: `Sort<int, index_sequence<4,5,6,1,2,7>, QuickSort, LessThan> quickSort;`

Comment: @prestokeys: Feel free to copy my "answer" in your question, it is the best I could do to reduce the issue.

Comment: As Jonathan Wakely noted (on an answer-comment I will delete) this is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65186, a simplified form of your example was added to the bug report, let's hope it helps gcc's developers to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename, int, template <typename U, U, U> class>
  struct Sort;
```

This is perfectly legal.

It could be redeclared like this, giving names to all the parameters:

```
template <typename T, typename T2, int I, template <typename U, U X, U Y> class TT>
  struct Sort;
```

It declares a class template `Sort` which has four template parameters, the type parameter `T`, a second type parameter `T2` (unnamed in the original), a non-type template parameter `I`, and a template template parameter `TT`.

The template template parameter `TT` must a class template taking three template parameters, `U` is a type parameter and the second and third (`X` and `Y`) are non-type template parameters of type `U`.

A suitable argument for the fourth template parameter of `Sort` might be something like:

```
template <typename T, T t1, T t2>
  class Foo
  { static const bool value = t1 < t2; };
```

which would be instantiated like:

```
Foo<int, 1, 2> fi;
```

or

```
Foo<char, 'a', 'b'> fc;
```